# Design: Contrast is not correct in the new design

Tags: bug, design

Contrast should be used to make *useful* UI elements easy to find, and *blend in* less important elements.

In the current design, contrast is all backwards. It makes all the unimportant UI elements stick out, and all the elements that need to be visible are *basically hidden*.

**Two things** are necessary in order to fix this:

1. Make the unimportant UI elements *less contrasted*: background, minor links and callouts badges, logo
2. Make the important, "business" elements *more contrasted*.

You can achieve this by making the background lighter, the font on the left column bigger and bolder, and avoid the hideous super-saturated yellow and green, in favour of more natural tints.

Please refer to the image below:

[image: Design]

Comment: Please note: Sean's [original design](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/skeptics-brand-concept-and-site-design) had a much better yellow!

Comment: Ironically, it took me a while to see the "Too little contrast" text in the diagram.

Comment: Sorry, @sean, the issue is still there. You fixed some buttons which is not what I specified above...

Answer (score 2):

## Example with better/proper contrast

I've also fixed the font size to something less "insane" :-)

CSS [here](http://pastebin.com/usLRN8cz)

[image]

Comment: I was thinking that the meta version of the background might also look nice on the main site, it's less dark. That might have a similar effect to the background you used here.

Comment: @Fabian the meta BG has a very similar contrast to the color I've used in the example. The point of using a blue is that it would make the yellow a bit more tolerable :-)

Comment: Thanks - I think this is the biggest problem I have with the new design.  That and the letter spacing when you are typing and the color of the followed links.