# 404, Error, and Captcha Images: Suggestions Welcome

Tags: discussion, design

In response to [Sklivvz request](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3377/26048), we can update the 404, Error, and captcha images as part of site update, but I could use some help brainstorming images that better represent the community. Please post suggestions as answers below.

NOTE: In order to not delay the launch of the new design, we may retroactively change these after the new design goes live.

Here are the current images:

- bigfoot (404)

  [image: bigfoot]
- weird Darwin thing (captcha)

  [image: darwinoid]
- ufo (error)

  [image: ufo]

Comment: I'm in favor of the ufo error, also [featured here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/are-there-public-laws-dealing-with-extraterrestrial-contact)

Comment: Bigfoot is fine, but its height should be reduced.

Answer (score 18):

Vote on this if you think we deserve the original Big Foot image for the 404 page

[image: bigfoot color corrected]

Answer (score 10):

Vote on this if the artificially enhanced green and yellow of the original UFO image stabs your eyes, and want to use the original image for the 500 page, instead :-)

[image: ufo color corrected]

Comment: The wording confuses me. I see two versions of this image: the [greyscale with yellows](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/3385/7286) and this colour version. Both are described here as "original".

Comment: @Anko this image is the original, the other two are modified. The other two are part of the old skin of this site (hence: original), and this is a proposed change.

Answer (score 9):

Vote on this if you think Darwin is awesome even without weird gears instead of a brain and he will guard us from spam bots on the captcha page anyways:

[image: darwin]

Answer (score 6):

Vote on this if you think change is a mistake, and we should keep the ufo (error) page.

[image]

Comment: The problem is the *quality* of the image, not the *subject*. How do I vote?

Comment: Never mind, I've added [my own answer](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/3392/96) for that.

Answer (score 5):

Vote on this if you wish people would just leave well enough alone, and we should keep the bigfoot (404) page.

[image: bigfoot]

Answer (score 2):

Vote on this if you think there was never a remake better than the original, and we should keep the weird Darwin thing (CAPTCHA).

[image: darwinoid]

Answer (score 1):

Einstein on a bicycle (404):

[image]

Comment: Einstein found [so many things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein#Scientific_career) that I think his image is particularly unsuitable for a *Not Found* page.

Answer (score 1):

For the CAPTCHA, some (preferably original) variation of this quote:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For the 404 message:

> [image]

Comment: Could this be confusing? People might click on the "link".

Answer (score -2):

For the error page

> [image: Thoreau]

I stole it from [here](http://www.eattoperform.com/2015/08/29/5-things-i-wish-i-could-say-to-new-folks-at-the-gym-by-lisbeth-darsh/) - who knows where they stole it from.

Comment: I don't think a quote would look good on a 404 page :/